# Domain Driven Design in Java - Turning all primitives into Value Objects?

Tags: java, domain-driven-design

Does DDD in Java usually mean turning every possible primitive that's part of your domain into a value object? I've had a discussion with collegues today regarding Stringly (as opposed to Strongly) typed code with collegues today. I'm a big fan of turning everything into seperate Value Objects (well, anything that isn't an entity), but the overal sentiment was only to do this in case of a struct (like an address, with a street, house number, etc), or when built-in validation is relevant (like a phone number). Would putting other things, like for example a pet name into a separate wrapper class be overkill (even with frameworks like Lombok), or does it give any big advantages that aren't easy to discover on the first glance?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43162937/ddd-value-objects-to-cover-every-property

Answer (score 1):

That's not a rule, but your code should reflect your business language as much as possible. It's a good idea to change your primitive values to understandable business nouns. Even when your value objects are extremely simple (with just a single `value` property), it's much easier to reason about them when they are named explicitly. Besides that, your objects can (and will) change during the knowledge crunching of your model/domain. It's very possible, that some day your single-value objects will turn into more complex structures, possibly with complex validation. Refactoring is much easier, when you design your value objects as meaningful classes from the beginning. You also gain static type validation advantages, e.g. you can't set pet name as street address (which would be possible if you only modeled them as simple strings).

Answer (score 0):

> does it give any big advantages that aren't easy to discover on the first glance?

One big advantage is that it decouples your business logic from the representation of the data in memory.  For example, your invoicing logic doesn't really care if you represent money as an integer, or a long, or a fixed point, or a floating point.  It cares about things like applying a tax rate to a purchase price.

So the value types are more than just "tags" -- they are convenient places to put things like units, and rounding rules, and tracking important distinctions like pre tax and post tax.

The can also help tease out different concepts, making them explicit - is an `Address` a thing on a shipping label?  a location on a map? a property title? part of a tax jurisdiction? part of a legal jurisdiction?

Combine that with strong type safety, and you get some additional checks that a coding error hasn't introduced a business error (like summing pre and post tax amounts together).